# Как нарисовать через css clip-path (или другим способом) ровную дугу внутрь блока?

Tags: clip-path

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня стоит clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 70% 90%, 44% 87%, 23% 91%, 0 99%, 0 0);
Есть ли программы или сервисы в которых можно нарисовать такое ?
Нашел два сервиса , но оба неподходят под такую задачу.
Первый http://www.cssplant.com/clip-path-generator .
Второй https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/.

Comment: `clip-path-ом` не будет работать в `EDGE && IE`... Псевдо-элементом лучше, ну или `svg`

Answer (score 4):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.block::after {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Не плохо, для данного случая. Но вопрос был об SVG, когда дугой  с одной стороны не обойтись. Например, есть задача, обрезать изображение по форме прямоугольной, но немного выпуклой, так же как здесь, но со всех сторон. Как решить такой вопрос?

Comment: @Amsterdam, а где в вопросе что-то сказанное про `svg`?

Comment: @Amsterdam, если есть вопрос, то задай его и уверен тебе помогут.  Я не совсем понял на счет обрезать и немного выпуклой...

Comment: просто clipPath зачастую пересекается с SVG, поэтому и решение с ним может быть связано. Но дело в том, что clippath умеет рисовать либо ломаные, либо овалы и окружности, а вот с более сложными обтекаемыми фигурами уже не получается так просто

Comment: Не могу уловить ход мыслей....

Comment: Создал отдельный вопрос, если интересно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/932105/Нестандартное-изображение-clippath Уже несколько часов пытаюсь реализовать, но не могу понять как