# Как создать криволинейную форму clipPath

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

Для обрезки изображения используется clipPath

```
//HTML
<span class="clip-svg-inline2">
   <img src="templates/img/case-4.jpg" alt="">
</span>

//CSS
.clip-svg-inline2 {
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-polygon2");
  clip-path: url("#clip-polygon2");
}
//SVG
<svg>
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-polygon2" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <polygon points=".16 0, .40 .57, .40 1, .72 1, .72 .57, 1 0, .72 0, .57 .28, .48 0" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oxjatd5q/

Все работает. Но вопрос - возможно ли **вместо polygon** использовать свою форму, подключить код из **собственного SVG** или каким либо еще образом обрезать изображение именно по нарисованной фигуре.

Дело в том, что все фигуры clipPath построены на прямых и ломанных, а как нарисовать там округлое со всех сторон изображение? Картинка в примере с экраном старого телевизора не случайна, хотелось бы понять, как нарисовать подобный контур, где **с каждой стороны дуги и округлые края**.

Comment: Ну сделай ту фигуру в самом `svg` и сделай ее  `background-ОМ` элемента.  `background-image: url(путь svg файла);`

Comment: @Amsterdam так вам надо вырезать картинку по форме экрана TV?

Comment: @Air бэкграунд изображения перекроется img, вложенным в блок. Задача обрезать именно вложенные изображения по контуру фигуры.

Comment: Ты не понял. Картинка тоже должна быть в `svg`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да, нужно обрезать вложенное в блок изображение по форме экрана (но это просто пример формы, которую не получается создать при помощи фигур типа polygon и пр.), т.к. она со всем сторон состоит из дуг, которые там не задаются

Comment: @Air да, не совсем понял возможность реализации, поэтому интересно было бы увидеть код

Comment: @Amsterdam понял

Comment: @Amsterdam, думаю, Александр тебе поможет...

Comment: @Amsterdam, не потому что  я не хочу, просто Александр в `SVG` крут... У него лучше получиться

Comment: @Amsterdam загляните сюда, через час, полтора, подробно напишу как это делается

Comment: @Alexandr_TT большое спасибо! Загляну обязательно, так или иначе, хотя уже и ночь на дворе) но реализовать необходимо. Полдня уже потрачено, но решить задачу никак не получается. Звездочки, символы, трапеции, все это получается, но с формой телевизора - просто затык..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы получить точный контур, по которому будет вырезаться изображение необходимо сделать следующие шаги:

- Загрузить картинку в векторный редактор с помощью файла svg и тегов
  `<image>`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="960" height="630" viewBox="0 0 960 630" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
    
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKxce.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#clip1)" />
</svg>
```

- В векторном редакторе

  1. С помощью инструмента `рисовать кривые Безье` (цифра 1 на рисунке) нанести на контур узловые точки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Выделить узловые точки (цифра 2) для появления рычагов управления, с помощью которых будем корректировать форму кривой
3. Преобразовать узловые точки в автоматически сглаженные.
4. Сохраняем файл в векторном редакторе и забираем из него формулу
   патча, которая будет использоваться как `clip-path`, который точно
   повторяет экран TV

### SVG clipPath

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
 }
  svg image {
 clip-path:url(#clip1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 960 630" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  
    <defs>
     <clipPath id="clip1" >
   <path fill="black" d="m231.6 181.5c44.4-10.1 135.5-7.3 135.5-7.3 0 0 104-3.7 172.2 9.3 19.1 3.7 26.2 24.7 28 41.4 7 63.8 5.6 110 6 109.4 0 0 0.1 56.6-8 103.4-1.7 10.1-9.3 21.9-19.4 24-48.9 10.3-156.2 12-156.2 12 0 0-97.7-0.5-150.8-16-12.2-3.6-24.2-14.4-27.4-26.7-10.3-39.5-14.7-118.1-14.7-118.1 0 0-2.3-71.8 5.3-104.8 3-12.9 16.5-23.8 29.4-26.7z"/>
   </clipPath>
    </defs>

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKxce.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  />
</svg>  
</div>
```

*Вырезаем другую картинку*

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
 } 
 svg image {
 clip-path:url(#clip1);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 960 630" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
    <defs>
     <clipPath id="clip1" >
   <path fill="black" d="m231.6 181.5c44.4-10.1 135.5-7.3 135.5-7.3 0 0 104-3.7 172.2 9.3 19.1 3.7 26.2 24.7 28 41.4 7 63.8 5.6 110 6 109.4 0 0 0.1 56.6-8 103.4-1.7 10.1-9.3 21.9-19.4 24-48.9 10.3-156.2 12-156.2 12 0 0-97.7-0.5-150.8-16-12.2-3.6-24.2-14.4-27.4-26.7-10.3-39.5-14.7-118.1-14.7-118.1 0 0-2.3-71.8 5.3-104.8 3-12.9 16.5-23.8 29.4-26.7z"/>
   </clipPath>
    </defs>

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGmV9.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
```

### SVG Mask

С масками можно получить более интересные варианты

Для справки можно почитать статью - [Практические примеры применения масок svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748)

Вырезаем как `clipPath`, но оставляем полупрозрачным окружающий фон

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 960 630" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
    <defs>
     <mask id="msk1" >
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
   <path fill="white" d="m231.6 181.5c44.4-10.1 135.5-7.3 135.5-7.3 0 0 104-3.7 172.2 9.3 19.1 3.7 26.2 24.7 28 41.4 7 63.8 5.6 110 6 109.4 0 0 0.1 56.6-8 103.4-1.7 10.1-9.3 21.9-19.4 24-48.9 10.3-156.2 12-156.2 12 0 0-97.7-0.5-150.8-16-12.2-3.6-24.2-14.4-27.4-26.7-10.3-39.5-14.7-118.1-14.7-118.1 0 0-2.3-71.8 5.3-104.8 3-12.9 16.5-23.8 29.4-26.7z"/>
   </mask>
    </defs>

    
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGmV9.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>
</div>  

Другой вариант  

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

В этом варианте вырезается экран и показывается фон, который лежит ниже и одновременно показывается сам TV.

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 960 630" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
    <defs>
     <mask id="msk1" >
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <path fill="white" d="m231.6 181.5c44.4-10.1 135.5-7.3 135.5-7.3 0 0 104-3.7 172.2 9.3 19.1 3.7 26.2 24.7 28 41.4 7 63.8 5.6 110 6 109.4 0 0 0.1 56.6-8 103.4-1.7 10.1-9.3 21.9-19.4 24-48.9 10.3-156.2 12-156.2 12 0 0-97.7-0.5-150.8-16-12.2-3.6-24.2-14.4-27.4-26.7-10.3-39.5-14.7-118.1-14.7-118.1 0 0-2.3-71.8 5.3-104.8 3-12.9 16.5-23.8 29.4-26.7z"/>
   </mask>
    </defs>

           <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKxce.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGmV9.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />

   
</svg> 
</div>
```

### Пример с анимацией изображения TV

Добавляются две строчки анимации,- горизонтального и вертикального перемещения фоновой картинки

```
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGmV9.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" >
          <animate attributeName="x" dur="10s" values="0;135;0" repeatcount="indefinite" />
           <animate attributeName="y" dur="10s" values="0;20;90;90;20;20;90;90;70;50;20;0" repeatcount="indefinite" />
           </image>
```

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 960 630" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
    <defs>
     <mask id="msk1" >
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <path fill="white" d="m231.6 181.5c44.4-10.1 135.5-7.3 135.5-7.3 0 0 104-3.7 172.2 9.3 19.1 3.7 26.2 24.7 28 41.4 7 63.8 5.6 110 6 109.4 0 0 0.1 56.6-8 103.4-1.7 10.1-9.3 21.9-19.4 24-48.9 10.3-156.2 12-156.2 12 0 0-97.7-0.5-150.8-16-12.2-3.6-24.2-14.4-27.4-26.7-10.3-39.5-14.7-118.1-14.7-118.1 0 0-2.3-71.8 5.3-104.8 3-12.9 16.5-23.8 29.4-26.7z"/>
   </mask>
    </defs>

           <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKxce.jpg" x="0" width="100%" height="100%"  />
             
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGmV9.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" >
       <animate attributeName="x" dur="20s" values="0;135;0" repeatcount="indefinite" />
     <animate attributeName="y" dur="20s" values="0;20;90;90;20;20;90;90;70;50;20;0" repeatcount="indefinite" />
           </image> 

   
</svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за шикарно развернутый ответ! Но видите ли в чем дело - сами изображения находятся внутри слайдера, через тег img, поэтому и нужно было использовать вариант с присвоением класса элементу и передачи маски.

Получается, можно создать в path нужную форму, методом, описанным вами, и загрузить способом, как показано на примере Qwertiy ?

Правда, сейчас попробовал вставить ваш path с телевизором в тот пример, но почему то, ничего не отображается..

Comment: суть понял, получается! Осталось подогнать маску под изображения в слайдере, и готово. Спасибо огромное вам за такой содержательный ответ! Вы крайне выручили!

Comment: Пример с зомбоящиком мне очень понравился!

Answer (score 4):

1. В `clip-path` можно поместить любой `path`.
2. В `path` достаточно методов для рисования, в том числе кривые безье и дуги.

```css
html, body, main {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

svg {
  width: 10em;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

main {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, blue);
  clip-path: url(#heart-clip);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path id="heart" fill="orange" stroke="red" stroke-width=".01" d="M.1,0.3A.2,.2 0,0,1 .5,.3A.2,.20 0,0,1 .9,.3Q.9,.6 .5,.90Q.1,.6 .1,.3z" />

  <clipPath id="heart-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <use xlink:href="#heart" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>

<main></main>
```

PS: Данный пример не будет работать в EDGE и IE.

Comment: ♦ уточнение - в `clip-path` можно поместить не один, а сколько угодно патчей

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, у меня не работало с несколькими...

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо за ответ! Ваш пример так же, подходит.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, убрал слово "один".

Comment: @Air, зачем мне эта штука в шапке?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да шоб некоторые субъекты не приставали)))) Мол пример не верный))))

Comment: @Air, ну не в шапку же...

Comment: @Qwertiy,  ок...

Answer (score 4):

**Пример автора вопроса**

Чтобы заработало, нужно было убрать `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` так как при этом параметре путь вычисляется в процентах или в долях от единицы

Подставил патч, полученный в первом ответе

```css
.clip-svg-inline2 {
  display: block;
      -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-polygon2");
      clip-path: url("#clip-polygon2");
    }
```

```html
<span class="clip-svg-inline2">
       <img src="https://i-a.d-cd.net/1cda2es-960.jpg" alt="">
    </span>
    
    <svg>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip-polygon2" >
                    <path fill="black" d="m231.6 181.5c44.4-10.1 135.5-7.3 135.5-7.3 0 0 104-3.7 172.2 9.3 19.1 3.7 26.2 24.7 28 41.4 7 63.8 5.6 110 6 109.4 0 0 0.1 56.6-8 103.4-1.7 10.1-9.3 21.9-19.4 24-48.9 10.3-156.2 12-156.2 12 0 0-97.7-0.5-150.8-16-12.2-3.6-24.2-14.4-27.4-26.7-10.3-39.5-14.7-118.1-14.7-118.1 0 0-2.3-71.8 5.3-104.8 3-12.9 16.5-23.8 29.4-26.7z"/>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
```

PS: Данный пример не будет работать в EDGE && IE

Comment: понял, благодарю! Оказывается, всего одно значение мешало настроить вывод)

Comment: @Amsterdam  Я тоже доволен, что помог :) теорию изучайте, что означает каждый параметр. Это же быстро сделать, например https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clipPathUnits  и статью мою по маскам почитайте, на которую дал ссылку, там всё доходчиво изложено, но это понимание добыто кровью и потом, так сказать :))) Зато какие переспективы открываются, если осознанно использовать

Comment: бесспорно. svg вещь очень мощная, позволяет реализовывать в верстке бурные фантазии дизайнеров) Сейчас встал как раз такой случай, потребовалось искать решение. Благо есть svg и добрые люди, которые помогут в непростой ситуации. Спасибо вам еще раз! Изучение этой темы конечно же продолжу. Очень полезная вещь)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, но ведь тогда он будет не responsive?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88265/discussion-between-alexandr-tt-and-qwertiy).

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  можно небольшой вопрос, касательно уже непосредтсвенно моего случая? Картинка обрезается сейчас вот таким образом: http://prntscr.com/m7b0j1 Правильно ли я  понимаю, что это изза того, что "экран" обрамлен белой рамкой вокруг?

Comment: @Amsterdam белый фон это то, что не попало в clipPath/ Пробуйте его подвинуть влево и вверх   `<clipPath id="clip-polygon2" >
                    <path transform="translate(-120 200)" fill="black"`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT так совсем исчезло) Александр, а фигуру вы рисовали в Inkscape? В Иллюстраторе, как понимаю, можно сделать по аналогии, с помощью инструмента "Кривизна". Или удобнее использовать другой редактор?

Comment: @Amsterdam рисовал в Inkscape, попробуйте подбирать значения `translate`, посмотрите внимательно, может ошибка в синтаксисе. Не получится, задайте новый вопрос, но подробно, с родными картинками и вашим кодом

Comment: @Alexandr_TT в целом, все получается! Но, выходит, она обрезает конкретно заданную область. То есть, какого размера был svg, такую область по ширине и высоте обрежет. А возможно ли сделать, что бы обрезаемая фигурой область, растягивалась пропорционально ширине и высоте родительского блока, если тот будет менять свои размеры (например при адаптации страницы, или Hover эффекте, когда при наведении блок увеличивается по ширине и т.п)

Comment: @Amsterdam Привет, задайте отдельный вопрос, где всё это и напишите, будет быстрее и легче. Во-первых я увижу ваш код реализации и пойму возможно это или нет. Во-вторых, у вас повышаются шансы получить ответ, здесь много отвечающих специалистов.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT готово: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/932679/Масштабируемый-clippath

Comment: @Amsterdam увидел